# cell.imageView!.frame size change. Swift

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, uiimageview, cell

I can't find any reason why the cell.imageView change after I click the cell. It seems there is only width change. In my code, the image frame is supposed to be the iPhone one in the second picture.

imageView is the Swift built-in one, not my custom name from tableviewcell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    if tableView == resultsTable {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MarketCell")
        var supplyDetail = String()

        var frame = cell.imageView!.frame
        let imageSize = 50 as CGFloat
        frame.size.height = imageSize
        frame.size.width  = imageSize
        cell.imageView!.frame = frame
        cell.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = imageSize / 2.0
        cell.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Profile Picture")
        ...getDataInBackgroundWithBlock...
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
        return cell

    } 
}
```

Before click,

[image]

After click,

[image]

Comment: The code you posted suggests the image view should always be 50 by 50, yet you say the second image is correct, yet only one image view is 50 by 50. Post all of the code relevant to setting the size of the image view.

Comment: The correct one should be the iPhone one in the second picture. That is all the code relevant to the size of image. I tried to cross out all the lines from var frame to cell.imageView.clipToBounds. Same thing happens. I am wondering is there any thing I need to pay attention on attribute inspector?

Comment: Please don't show fake code summaries. Show real code.

Comment: updated. It is quite long. That's why I summarize it. LOL

Comment: Ahh. Are you using auto layout?

Comment: No. I am not using auto layout

Comment: Are you sure `if tableView == resultsTable` is true on the initial load? If you want it to always be 50 by 50, why not just set that in the XIB or when the image view is initialized?

Comment: I am sure it is resultsTable as I can see the title is right. what do you mean of XIB?

Comment: Maybe print something or set a breakpoint rather than just assume. For example, `if tableView == resultsTable { print("In here")` to make sure. By XIB, I mean the storyboard or the X Code Interface Builder file.

Comment: Yes. it did print "in here". Ya. I am also thinking is there anything I miss in storyboard like attribute inspector

Comment: Just upload a screen shot of storyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the UITableViewCell's imageView property you are kind of accepting it on Apple's terms. Namely that it will be sized to the height of the cell and appear to the left of any default labels with contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit. To have an UIImageView sized to your own specifications you can either, subclass UITableView and create your own prototype cell, my personal suggestion, or you can override simply override layoutSubviews like so:

```
override func layoutSubviews(){
    super.layoutSubview()
    self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0,width:40.0,height:40.0) //Or whatever frame you think is necessary
}
```

You could also just add an UIImageView as a subview to cell.contentView and remove all of cell.contentView's subviews after it has been dequeued.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Right now, I want to keep the picture size based on the height of the cell. So, I delete the code that change the size of imageView, but same thing happen. Is that normal?

Comment: Hi. I find the thing that cause this happen. It is from getDataInBackgroundWithBlock. I change it to try! ...getData(). Then it works perfect.